# Hibernate @Formula not working in Spring boot Tests when using @DataJpaTest

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, junit5

I'm trying to write an integration test for a java spring project.
At some point in the code I need to check `customer.getId()`, where the ID  is created by a `@Formula` annotation like this: (keep in mind `Customer_Id` is my auto-incrementing primary key)

```java
@Formula("Customer_Id")
private int id
```

I use `lombok` to generate getters and setters methods. My database for testing is H2 and I use `Junit5` for my tests. The problem i'm facing is that i cannot test the `getId()` behavior because it's always `0` when I annotate the tests with `@DataJpaTest`. I made it work with `@SpringBootTest` but I would like to stick to sliced tests.

Is there a way to make `@DataJpaTest` work with `@Formula`s ?

Thanks in advance.

```java
@Entity(name="customers")
@Table(name="Customers")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Customer{

    @Formula("Customer_Id")
    private int id;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="Customer_Id", unique=true, nullable=false, precision=10)
    private int customerId;
}
```

```java
// if it is annotated with @SpringBootTest the tests passes
@DataJpaTest
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@EnableJpaAuditing
class MyClassTests {

    @Autowired
    private CustomerRepository customerRepository;

    @Test
    void given_a_customer_should_have_customerId_and_id_equal(){
        Customer customer = new Customer();
        customerRepository.save(customer);
        // if i don't call findOneByCustomerId test fails for both @SpringBootTest and @DataJpaTest
        customer = customerRepository.findOneByCustomerId(customer.getCustomerId());
        assertEquals(customer.getCustomerId(), customer.getId()); // expected: 1, actual 0
    }
}
```

Comment: It is unclear why do you need duplicate the `customerId` in so strange way? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Good point. My Customers table doesn't follow naming conventions but I still need to have formulas so that I can query against a field called id even though my table doesn't have it, though.

Comment: You can simply rename `customerId` to `id` and it will work, because you explicitly specified the column name via `@Column` annotation.

Comment: @SternK In this contrived example formula can be avoided - but what happens with complicated formulas that still need to be tested and DataJpaTest is used as a slice test?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use `@DataJpaTest`

> By default, data JPA tests are **transactional and roll back** at the end
> of each test. See the [relevant section](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.1/reference/html/testing.html#testcontext-tx-enabling-transactions) in the Spring Framework
> Reference Documentation for more details

If you use `@SpringBootTest` that is not the case.
But, if you add `@Transational` to your Class, the test will fail.

Solution:

```
@DataJpaTest
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.NOT_SUPPORTED)
class MyClassTests {
  ...
```

> Propagation.NOT_SUPPORTED states that if a physical transaction
> exists, then it will be suspended before continuing. This physical
> transaction will be automatically resumed at the end. After this
> transaction is resumed, it can be rolled back (in case of a failure)
> or committed.

Comment: But I don't understand why `@Formula` won't be resolved when the tests are transactional? Is there an explanation for that?